# insert html into database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to enable users to edit pages with editor (CKEditor).

The problem is that I want to prevent XSS, so when I'm using:

```
$this->input->post('content', TRUE)
```

it also removes some html conent, for example, the following code:

```
<script></script><p><span style="color:#800000;">text</span></p>
```

becomes to:

```
[removed][removed]<p><span
```

So yes, it prevents XSS, but also removes some necessary html content.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: For starters, don't alter the content at all before you save it. XSS only occurs when you *output* something into a context that can execute javascript. If you filter prematurely, you can't take advantage of improved filters later, and you can't review the original content.

Comment: Use ActiveRecord and you do not have to worry about escaping characters to DB.

Comment: @Winston: XSS and SQL injection (or non-malicious syntax breaking DB queries due to failure to escape properly) have no connection whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use their built in XSS functionality. Use [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to do it for you. That way you have more control over what is and isn't removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way change this code `$this->input->post('content', TRUE)` into `$_POST['content']` its work for me because codeigniter will do XSS filtering when run `$this->input`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this you can use below code.

$content = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('content'));

The save to database and at the time of retrieval, you can use

htmlspecialchars_decode('your html code');

Comment: This doesn't address the XSS problem (or any problem, what's the point?).